# mdbootstrap tabs error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: mdbootstrap

When i want to use mdbootstrap tabs here https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/navigation/tabs/#section-buttons , i have in the console.log (on click events on tabs)

```
input.js:341 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

What more do i need to correct this ?

My jsfiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/1zekermit/cv7xywp1/1/.

I see this error appears even in the mdbootstrap website, so, can i pay no attention to it ?

Comment: I have the same issue, nearly 2y after :D